# why static final int MAX_VALUE=100; gives compile time error

Tags: java

```
        public class A{
          public static void main(String[] args){
           static final int MAX_VALUE = 100; //COMPILE TIME ERROR
           System.out.println("MAX_VALUE");
          }
        }
```

Why `static final int MAX_VALUE=100`; gives compile time error, it gives the error as **"illegal modifier for parameter MAX_VALUE;only final is permitted "**

Comment: `static` variables cannot be inside method . Remove the modifier `static` !

Comment: In java I think static variables can not be in a method like C/C++

Comment: +1 for reminding the OP about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare static variable inside methods.
Static variables belong to the class; variables declared inside a method are local variables and belong to that method.

Answer (score 1):

A local variable can not be static. You can either create a final local variable, or a final static class variable (which are actually constants, btw.), but not a local static variable:

```
public class A{
    static final int CLASS_CONST = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       final int LOCAL_CONST = 43;

       ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Static variables belong to the class.Not methods**

The variables declared inside a `method` are `local variables` and belong to that `method`.

So it becomes

```
final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
```

Prefer to read :  [Docs on Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `static` cannot be used inside methods. This would be valid code:

```
public class A{

   static final int MAX_VALUE = 100; // This line can't go in a method.

   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("MAX_VALUE: "+MAX_VALUE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delcare `static` things inside a method.  Move it up a line.

Answer (score 0):

you can't create static final in a method, you must create it outside the method:

```
public class A {
          static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

          public static void main(String[] args){
             System.out.println("MAX_VALUE");
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should declare this constant in the class A, not in the `main()` method

```
public class A{

    static final int MAX_VALUE = 100; //COMPILE TIME ERROR

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("MAX_VALUE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class A{
      public static void main(String[] args){
       static final int MAX_VALUE = 100; //COMPILE TIME ERROR
       System.out.println("MAX_VALUE");
      }
    }
```

To

```
public class A{
      static final int MAX_VALUE = 100; //NO ERROR YAY!!

      public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("MAX_VALUE");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

static variables are class level variables ,you can't declare them at method.
According [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

```
Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.  
This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the static
modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. 
They are associated with the class, rather than with any object
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out that static members belong to the class instead of a specific instance. So you don't have to create a class instance to use a static member, rather you can call SomeClass.SOME_STATIC_MEMBER directly.

You cannot call any other member of a class that is not static without instantiating that class. Meaning if you have-

```
public class SomeClass {

    public int add (int x, int y){
        return x + y;
    }

}
```

For you to use *add* method of SomeClass above, you have to instantiate first-

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
int sum = someClass.add(5, 10);
```

So, there is no point of allowing us to declare static members in a non-static method as for us to use that method, we have to instatiate the class where that method belongs to.